# Ubuntu Server VirtualBox host-only network

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, virtualbox

I want to prototype a web application and I used to do this with an Ubuntu VM (using VMWare) using LAMP stack to host the webapp.

Unfortunately, I have to use a PC with less hardware resources so I need to instead run Ubuntu Server 20.04 as it is less hardware intensive. On top of this I need to use VirtualBox instead of VMware so I am unfamiliar with its networking.

All I need is to be able to have the host communicate with the Ubuntu Server VM. However, I am unsure about how to go about this as tutorials are lacking.

I've created a Host-Only adapter `192.168.56.1/24` and assigned it to Adapter 1 in the VM. (Here is where I think I'm stuck) I then tried to assign the adapter ensp0s3 a static IP using netplan (assuming it is the host only adapter) with `192.168.56.10`.

**Problem**

With this I am able to ping `192.168.56.10` from the host. However, I can't ping anything from within the VM.

I believe I have messed this setup but am unsure about how to fix it.

Any advice is appreciated!

**Edit:**

I've now created a second adapter with NAT so that I can still have internet access. And the other (host-only) adapter is now a bridged adapter with `192.168.1.3`.

I can ping `192.168.1.3` from the host and from the guest I can ping other devices on the network **except** for the host.

**Question**

Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: @user535733 I've currently got two adapters going at the moment. A NAT and a Bridged that was host-only previously. 
The bridged was able to get a DHCP IP assigned. I can ping everything else in the network except the host, is this normal?

Comment: @user535733 Sorry forgot to do that, edited now.